# can i mark notification as already read , using the graph api?

Tags: php, c++, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this to get a notification list:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications/?include_read=0
```

Now I'd like to mark them as read, how do I do this?

Comment: i didnt try any thing , i have no idea where and what to try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should issue a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/%notification_id%?unread=false` where %notification_id% is the notification identifier you've received earlier (usually  something like 'notif_XXXXX_YYYYY').
If you want to mark all notifications read, you can perform a batch request.