# Facebook Graph API : mark notification as read, does it work?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm trying facebook Graph API calls into the Graph API Explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/notifications ).

I can get notifications with this call " me/notifications ".

Then, I want to mark notifications as read, but it doesn't seem to work. I choose a notification id and I tried several ways :

- notif_100007738631831_980288?unread=0
- notif_100007738631831_980288/?unread=0
- notif_100007738631831_980288?unread=false
- notif_100007738631831_980288/?unread=false
- notif_100007738631831_980288/?read=1

I get the notification informations, but the unread value is always " 1 " and the " unseen_count " when I get back all notifications has always the same value.

Any idea ? 
What do I make wrong ?

Thanks for your help ! :)

(Sorry for my bad english... :( )

Comment: I don’t see anything in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/notification/ that says this would be possible … did you find info saying otherwise anywhere?

Comment: I saw some questions on stackoverflow like these : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220212/can-i-mark-notification-as-already-read-using-the-graph-api
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263262/how-mark-a-facebook-notification-as-read-via-facebook-api
Isn't the same way as mine ?

Comment: I don’t know if your way is the same … did you make it a POST request …?

Comment: Oh no, I was trying in GET ! 
You're right, when I tried in POST, I had " true " as return, and the "reading status" is updated !! 
Thanks a lot !! :)